# How to edite li items from separate input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i work with **li** and i have issues.

I have input field, which add dynamically values to **list**, after adding some values, i have function to edite, this value, but this func work not correct, after editing li, it's delete all classes and span button.

HTML:

```
<form class="qa-form">
                <input type="text" class="qa-input" placeholder="Enter text">
                <button class="qa-button" id="btn-add">+</button>
                <button class="qa-button hidden" id="btn-save">Save</button>
            </form>
            <div class="item-list"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.qa-form {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.qa-input {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0.7rem 115px 0.7rem 0.7rem;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbce;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #3a3d4b;
}

.qa-button {
    position: absolute;
    background: #31353D;
    padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    right: 4px;
    transform: translateY(2.5px);
}

.list-view ul {

    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.list-view li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #efefef;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.list-view li:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #f7f7f7;
}

.completed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: gray;
}

.slide {
    display: none;
}


.list-view li span {
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}

.delete-item {
    float: right;
    background-color: #dc3545;
}

.edite-item {
    float: right;
    background-color: #fe6d00;

}

.correct-answ {
    float: left;
    background-color: #28a745;
}


.list-view li:hover span {
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.correct-answer-active {
    background-color: rgba(42, 176, 49, 0.45);
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".item-list").append("<ul id='item-data' class='list-view col-12'></ul>")

$("#btn-add").click(function () {
    var inputVal = $(".qa-input").val()
    if (inputVal != "") {
        $("#item-data").append("<li><span class='delete-item'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></span> <span class='edite-item'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></span><span class='correct-answ'><i class='fa fa-check-circle-o'></i></span>" + inputVal + "</li>");
        $(".qa-input").val(null)

    } else {
        alert("Add answer to input field")
    }
});


$(document).on("click", ".delete-item", function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
})

$(document).on("click", ".edite-item", function () {
    var listValues = $(this).parent();
    $("#btn-add").hide()
    $("#btn-save").show();
    $(".qa-input").val(listValues.text())
    editeData(listValues)
});

function editeData(val) {
    $("#btn-save").click(function () {
        var inputValue = $(".qa-input").val()
        if (val === inputValue) {
            alert("You are not make changes")
        } else {
            val.text(inputValue)
            $("#btn-add").show()
            $("#btn-save").hide();
           $(".qa-input").val(null)
        }
    });
}


$(document).on("click", ".correct-answ", function () {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "rgba(42, 176, 49, 0.45)")
    $(this).parent().attr('active', true);
});
```

So, i try to find mistake, during all day, and i can't

Comment: Can you share your `<ul><li>...</li></ul>` html?

Comment: @MarceloTheWizzardCoder it's creating dynamycaly in js script

Comment: @MarceloTheWizzardCoder ```$("#btn-add").click(function () {``` in this func

Comment: I know it, but can you create some items and then add here the generated html?

Comment: First *potential* issue is that each time you click edite-item, it adds a *new* handler to #btn-save, but shouldn't cause the problem you're describing

Comment: @MarceloTheWizzardCoder ```<ul id="item-data" class="list-view col-12"><li> 2131245215125ggg</li><li><span class="delete-item"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span> <span class="edite-item"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></span><span class="correct-answ"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></span>12312214</li><li><span class="delete-item"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span> <span class="edite-item"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></span><span class="correct-answ"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></span>123123123</li></ul>```
If you can see first item i edite ```<li> 2131245215125ggg</li>```,

Comment: @MarceloTheWizzardCoder and this li have anny class and spans

Comment: @MarceloTheWizzardCoder There is no need to have the generated code added.

Comment: Your `<button>`s default to `type=submit` so your page is resetting as the form is submitting.   Add `<button type='button'` to each button.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `.text()` will also alter your html as you already experienced.

You could replace `val.text(inputValue)` with `$(val).contents().last()[0].textContent = inputValue;`

There is also a problem with this line `if (val === inputValue) {` your `val` represents the `<li>` object, and `inputValue` is ofc the text from the input field, so those will never be the same.

**Working demo**

```js
$(".item-list").append("<ul id='item-data' class='list-view col-12'></ul>")

$("#btn-add").click(function() {
  var inputVal = $(".qa-input").val()
  if (inputVal != "") {
    $("#item-data").append("<li><span class='delete-item'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></span> <span class='edite-item'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></span><span class='correct-answ'><i class='fa fa-check-circle-o'></i></span><span class='val'>" + inputVal + "</span></li>");
    $(".qa-input").val(null)

  } else {
    alert("Add answer to input field")
  }
});


$(document).on("click", ".delete-item", function() {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
})
var edited = null
$(document).on("click", ".edite-item", function() {
  var listValues = $(this).closest("li");
  $("#btn-add").hide()
  $("#btn-save").show();
  $(".qa-input").val(listValues.find(".val").text())
  edited = listValues
});

$("#btn-save").click(function() {
  var pretext = edited.find(".val").text();
  var inputValue = $(".qa-input").val()
  if (pretext === inputValue) {
    alert("You are not make changes")
  } else {
    edited.find(".val").text(inputValue)
    $("#btn-add").show()
    $("#btn-save").hide();
    $(".qa-input").val("")
  }
});


$(document).on("click", ".correct-answ", function() {
  $(this).parent().css("background-color", "rgba(42, 176, 49, 0.45)")
  $(this).parent().attr('active', true);
});
```

```css
.qa-form {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.qa-input {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0.7rem 115px 0.7rem 0.7rem;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbce;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #3a3d4b;
}

.qa-button {
  position: absolute;
  background: #31353D;
  padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  right: 4px;
  transform: translateY(2.5px);
}

.list-view ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-view li {
  margin-top: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #efefef;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #666;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.list-view li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: gray;
}

.slide {
  display: none;
}

.list-view li span:not(.val) {
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
  width: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.delete-item {
  float: right;
  background-color: #dc3545;
}

.edite-item {
  float: right;
  background-color: #fe6d00;
}

.correct-answ {
  float: left;
  background-color: #28a745;
}

.list-view li:hover span {
  width: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.correct-answer-active {
  background-color: rgba(42, 176, 49, 0.45);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="qa-form">
  <input type="text" class="qa-input" placeholder="Enter text">
  <button type="button" class="qa-button" id="btn-add">+</button>
  <button type="button" class="qa-button hidden" id="btn-save">Save</button>
</form>
<div class="item-list"></div>
```

Comment: When i try to edite the all field, one from list are disappear

Comment: Try to add 3 values, and edit them with 2 times biger message

Comment: @Andrew Try run the demo now. I believe the problem is the click function inside the `editeData` function. I've moved your click event out and changed the code  a little bit.